# WebStorm 2018.3 Run/Debug start direct error

Tags: webstorm

The error message:

> Error running 'debug': Unknown error

and it is OK when I use previous version

this is my config

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Nearly everything is not correct - interpreter, parameters, etc.
Suggested configuration:

[image]

Comment: according to your configuration, it can work now. thank you